# swift framework: code changed and the built framework not update?

Tags: swift, compilation, frameworks, audiokit

> Environment: mac OS, Catalina, I tried on iOS simulator

AudioKit framework's structure is like this

[image: 111]

I added the following code , rebuild the xcode target, and the change is not updated in the new framework

```
// see the right channel data
public class Table: NSObject, MutableCollection, Codable {
    public
    convenience init?(rhs file: AVAudioFile) {
        let size = Int(file.length)
        self.init(count: size)

        guard let data = file.toFloatChannelData() else { return nil }
        
        for i in 0 ..< size {
            self[i] = data[1][i]
        }
   }
}
```

I have tried `Product -> Clear Build folder` , both on target `AudioKit` and `Cookbook`

I have tried `Product -> Clear Build folder` , and put `alt`, on both

I have tried to quit Xcode , and reboot MBP

Still not work.

How to update the swift framework.

Comment: I'm sorry but your question is not very clear.